# Differential of discount process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance

I am studying financial mathematics and I am trying to show that if the discount process is
$$
D(t)=\text{exp} \left[-\int_0^t R(s) ds\right]
$$
then its differential is
$$
dD(t)=-D(t)R(t)dt.
$$
I think that this should be quite easy to show and I am guessing that Itô's lemma could be used. However, my book just states that this holds without showing it. What confuses me is that $D(t)$ depends on the path of $R(t)$. Am I still allowed to write $D(t)$ as $f(t, R(t))$ and then apply Itô's lemma?

Comment: No need for Ito's lemma here since you'll never take a differential of $R$ (which may or may not be random). The result you have written is a Calculus I result.

Comment: OK, thank you! I thought that I hade to do something more complicated than that :)